# Label on grammar environment

Tags: captions, syntax

I want to have a caption and label on my grammar environment, and have implemented the solution here: [How to use caption and label in grammar environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/how-to-use-caption-and-label-in-grammar-environment) got my grammar displayed with a caption and a label as I want to, but I have a very large grammar which cannot be on one page. How can I get the newFloat solution to work with a grammar divided over multiple pages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! A long grammar might be better solved by using a subsection, rather than a floating object with a caption.

Answer (score 4):

Floats can never be split across pages.

A long grammar is probably best treated as a (sub)section with its title, rather than a float.

If you insist on floats, you have to split the grammar by hand into two floats and use `\ContinuedFloat` (see the documentation of `caption`).